# Is there a tool that will list the properties that are bound to in a XAML file?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have created a fairly complex view in XAML, and am performing a view-first MVVM implementation with this view. It's now time to go off and work on the ViewModel.

Is there a tool that will parse the XAML and list all the properties I need to implement?

Comment: Can you not just search for the keyword `Binding` in your XAML view? This should tell you where you've intended to expose data bound values.

Comment: Sure, but then I have to step through and write down (copy/type) the property names into another document. If I do a "Find in Files", I get the whole line of XAML in the results. I would like to see only the property names (and maybe the type of control or whatever) they are bound to in a list that's easy for a human to parse.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a tool available that does this. If there was, I assume it would be a Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: Resharper. There is no life without it. Mostly for the XAML / WPF Developer

Comment: If Resharper can really do this, post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Unfortunately, development is not my primary job function and Resharper isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a long shot, but you could run the app and get the list of binding errors from the debug output.